# How do I prevent OC4J change the windows Color to basic?

Tags: java, windows, jdeveloper, oc4j

Every time  i start the oc4j in jdeveloper it changes the windows color to basic, is ther a way to prevent it? Maybe with the configuration file or something? by the way I am using Windows 7 (64 bits) and jdeveloper 10g.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run menu > sysdm.cpl > Advanced Tab > performance > select adjust for best performance > make sure you do not allow Windows to choose for you because your computer does not know whats best --- Make sure Enable Aero Peek is checked